# Using libcurl in C++ android application using CMake

Tags: android, c++, cmake

Maybe there is already some answers on this forum about this problem, but i tried a lot of solutions already, and i still didnt solve this problem.

I have to make an android application using C++, wich uses libcurl.

And whatever i do, i can't run my program because it doenst find the library.

In my .cpp, i use this line :

```
#include <curl/curl.h>
```

And this is my CMakeLists.txt

```
# Sets the minimum version of CMake required to build the native
# library. You should either keep the default value or only pass a
# value of 3.4.0 or lower.

cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.4.1)

# Creates and names a library, sets it as either STATIC
# or SHARED, and provides the relative paths to its source code.
# You can define multiple libraries, and CMake builds it for you.
# Gradle automatically packages shared libraries with your APK.

add_library( # Sets the name of the library.
             native-lib

             # Sets the library as a shared library.
             SHARED

             # Provides a relative path to your source file(s).
             # Associated headers in the same location as their source
             # file are automatically included.
             src/main/cpp/native-lib.cpp )

# Searches for a specified prebuilt library and stores the path as a
# variable. Because system libraries are included in the search path by
# default, you only need to specify the name of the public NDK library
# you want to add. CMake verifies that the library exists before
# completing its build.

find_library( # Sets the name of the path variable.
              log-lib
              -lcurl

              # Specifies the name of the NDK library that
              # you want CMake to locate.
              log
              -lcurl )

# Specifies libraries CMake should link to your target library. You
# can link multiple libraries, such as libraries you define in the
# build script, prebuilt third-party libraries, or system libraries.




INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES($/usr/include/)

target_link_libraries( # Specifies the target library.
                       native-lib
                       -lcurl

                       # Links the target library to the log library
                       # included in the NDK.
                       ${log-lib} )
```

I used the commands :

`sudo aptitude install libcurl4-gnutls-dev`

and

`sudo aptitude install libcurl-dev`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should rather use the built-in functionality to integrate libcurl:

```
[...]

find_package(CURL REQUIRED)
include_directories(${CURL_INCLUDE_DIRS})
add_library(native-lib SHARED src/main/cpp/native-lib.cpp) 
target_link_libraries(native-lib ${CURL_LIBRARIES})
```

As it seems you are cross-compiling for Android, the following will make the curl library that you installed for your Ubuntu available for the compilation (add it before what is above).

```
set(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_LIBRARY BOTH)
set(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_INCLUDE BOTH)
set(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_PACKAGE BOTH)
```

But it might then be problematic in the linking step, since you installed the library for your Ubuntu and the program you want to compile it with is for Android. 
If this does not work, try to have the curl library in your cross-compiling toolset (but I don't know enough about it to tell you how to do it).

Comment: Hi, thanks for you answer
When i use this, i got this error :   Could NOT find CURL (missing: CURL_LIBRARY CURL_INCLUDE_DIR)

Comment: Can you try `set(CURL_INCLUDE_DIR "/usr/include")` before the above (if "curl/curl.h" is located there)?

Comment: Well i think it's a piece of solution because now i only got this :
  Could NOT find CURL (missing: CURL_LIBRARY) (found version "7.47.0")

Comment: @SamyLeGalloudec You tagged your question as Android, are you cross-compiling? This might need a modification if you do.

Comment: I'm programming an application from my computer for an android smartphone. I don't know if it's exaclty cross compilation (sorry for the lack of knowledge..)

Comment: Thanks a lot for helping, I put this line after the "set" that you told me set(CURL_LIBRARY "-lcurl") , and this is working. I have other errors but now my program finds the library
Should i still put you 3 lines above all this ?

Comment: @SamyLeGalloudec I am not sure... It might help about the other errors.

Comment: Well it's not, the build failed. I don't really understand this error, and it's way too big to copy it here

Comment: @SamyLeGalloudec In the ideal case you would install libcurl for your Android development environment, then it would be enough to have the first code snippet of this answer. But I don't know how this is done.

Comment: I think the problem with libcurl is solved, and now it is just a problem of bad CMakeLists.txt
But thanks a lot for helping me
Best Regards

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to instruct cmake to find the libcurl dependency.
Please read [How_To_Find_Libraries](https://cmake.org/Wiki/CMake:How_To_Find_Libraries).
And look at [find_package](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/command/find_package.html) and [FindCURL module](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/module/FindCURL.html)

As a quick-start, add the following to your CMakeLists.txt:

```
find_package(CURL REQUIRED)  
include_directories(${CURL_INCLUDE_DIRS})  
add_library(native-lib SHARED  ... )
target_link_libraries(native-lib ${CURL_LIBRARIES})
```

(even better: use target_include_directories() instead of include_directories()).

Comment: Hi, thanks for you answer. Same as i said to oLen, i don't really know what i have to put in (${CURL_INCLUDE_DIRS})
Should i put ${/usr/include/curl} or directly /usr/include... ?
Sorry if i ask beginner questions, first time i do a CMakeFile

Comment: Just write exactly "${CURL_INCLUDE_DIRS}", it's a variable filled by find_package(), if libcurl is found (i.e. installed as Linux package as in your case), please read the links I've included in my answer for more details.

Comment: When i let it exactly as you put it, i got this error :
  Could NOT find CURL (missing: CURL_LIBRARY CURL_INCLUDE_DIR)

Do you think it comes from the installation ?